# a SPECIFIC sprite- touch detection

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

since i havnt got an answer in my previos post, and no one solve that problem , i am asking this again. there is no 1 explanation regarding this.

i need to detect a sprite touch, a SPECIFIC one. in cocos2d+box2d.

lets say i have sprite `CCSprite *ran` that has a body, BUT , i have **many** of it .

if i detect a touch with the `ccTouchesBegan` , and use the `if(CGRectContainsPoint(particularSpriteRect, currentPosition))`

i will detect the touch in `ran` but i dont know who ran is this from all, and i need to destroy than specific `ran` , which i cant know who it was .

i find the best way to do that, as i do with contact listener that gives me the specific sprite user data :

```
CCSprite *actora = (CCSprite*)bodyA->GetUserData();   
CCSprite *actorb = (CCSprite*)bodyB->GetUserData();
```

and then i know that actora is what needs to be destroy cause i have his user data.

```
[self removeChild:actora cleanup:YES];
```

so , again , i need to detect a sprite touch and KNOW who it was,cause i have many `ran's`.
i guess its something needs to involve the userData .

any direction please ?
thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i have got it :

this is what i do, to destroy the specific body, different from what was said here :

put the next code in the touch method :

```
CGPoint currentPosition = [touch locationInView: [touch view]]; 
 currentPosition = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: currentPosition];

    b2Vec2 locationWorld = b2Vec2(currentPosition.x/PTM_RATIO, currentPosition.y/PTM_RATIO);

    for (b2Body* b = world->GetBodyList(); b; b = b->GetNext()) 
    {
        b2Fixture *bf1 = b->GetFixtureList();
        if (bf1->TestPoint(locationWorld))
        {
            CCSprite *tempSprite = (CCSprite *) b->GetUserData();
            if (tempSprite .tag==2 || tempSprite .tag==3) 
            {
                [self removeChild:tempSprite cleanup:YES];
                world->DestroyBody(b);

            }
        }
    }
```

here if you touch the right sprite(tagged) , it get destroyed .